# How to remove a row from a table cell?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table and I want to a remove certain row on a button in the table cell.

```
<table id='t_master'>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table data generated from database. I've tried using :

```
$(".btn_remove").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('#t_master').find('tr').remove();
});
```

But, it removes all the `t_master` rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery to get the `tr` of the closest `t_child` class and then remove it.

```js
$(".btn_remove").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.t_child').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='t_master'>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'>Add</button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'>Remove</button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'>Add</button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'>Remove</button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'>Add</button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove'>Remove</button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add ID to every `<TR>` and bind that ID to the button:

```js
  $(".btn_remove").on('click', function(e){
    var row = $(this).attr("data");    
    $("#"+row).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='t_master'>
<tr id="1">
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove' data='1'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove' data='2'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
   <td>XXX</td>
   <td>YYY</td>
   <td>
       <table class='t_child'>
       <tr>
          <td><button class='btn_add'></button></td>
          <td><button class='btn_remove' data='3'></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn_remove').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parents('tr').parents('tr').first().remove();
});
```

> $(this) represent the remove button.
>
> *.parents('tr') represent *'s parent 'tr' block.

Check on that: https://jsfiddle.net/onurgule/57rtfh8w/1/